# javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination for "Crtl + +"

Tags: java, javafx

What is the right format for defining KeyCombination as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>?

I tried:

```
zoomIn.setAccelerator(KeyCombination.keyCombination("Ctrl + +"))
```

but I get:

> IllegalArgumentException: Cannot parse key binding Ctrl + +"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change code and try using KeyCodeCombination class in below way

In Desktop keyboard

```
 zoomIn.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.ADD, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN));
```

In MacBook keyboard

```
zoomIn.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.EQUALS, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN));
```

Comment: thnx it did work with `zoomIn.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.ADD, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN));` In Desktop KeyBoard. So i suppose you inverted between MacBook Keyboard code and Desktop keyboard code ? (I dont have a macbook so i can't be sure :) )